# What is the difference between cēvēre and crīsāre?

Tags: classical-latin, profanity, synonyms, word-comparison

According to Wikipedia, cēvēre loosely means the actions of a female during intercourse, whereas crīsāre is the same but with anal sex. It later states however that cēvēre refers only to the actions of a passive homosexual man in intercourse. This is somewhat contradictory, so what is the difference?

Comment: I don't know enough for a definite answer, but I do know that in homosexual relationships, the passive partner was considered to be feminine. Therefore, the actions of a passive male/male partner could be the same as of a female.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionaries are notoriously bad at describing sex acts. Thankfully, J. N. Adams rectified that with his *The Latin Sexual Vocabulary* (Baltimore, 1982). I can add little to what he says of the two words (p. 136–137):

> (vii) *Criso* and *ceueo*
>
> Latin possessed two technical terms for types of sexual motion (in both cases that of the passive partner), *criso* and ceueo*. *Criso* indicated the motions of the female in intercourse: note ps.-Acron Hor. *Serm*. 2.7.50 'idest dum ego iaceo supinus et ipsa supra me crisat'...The passage in ps.-Acron should not be taken as implying that *criso* was appropriate only to the schema with the woman astride.
>
> *Ceueo* was used of the corresponding movements of the male pathic (cf. *ceuulus = 'pathic', *CGL* IL.357.20)...

Interestingly, he goes on to say that these are not very offensive words compared to something like *futuo*.

Comment: It seems to me that Adams outranks Wikipedia by a great deal. Rather than reconciling the definitions, my impulse is just to go with Adams. (Though "to think of the *cēvére* to mean passive actions" is odd syntax, so perhaps you've left out a word or something.)

Comment: So is there a difference between criso ceueo and the passive form of futuo (futuor)?